# Trie Node implmentation in C

Tags: c, trie

I am working in the LZW algorithm with Trie data structure. The problem I am having is my function InsertTrie is supposed to add a new Node and link to the previous

```
enter code here
typedef struct TrieNode {
    short codes[256];
    struct *TrieNode links[258];
} TrieNode;
typedef struct LZWCmp {
    TrieNode *head;   * Head pointer to first TrieNode 
    CodeSink sink;    * Code sink to send bits to 
    void *sinkState;  * Unknown object to send to sink for state 
    int nextCode;     * Next code to be assigned 
    int numBits;      * Number of bits per code currently 
    int maxCode;      * Max code that fits in numBits bits 
    UInt nextInt;     * Partially-assembled next int of output 
    int bitsUsed;     * Number of valid bits in top portion of nextInt 
    TrieNode *curLoc; * Current position in trie 
    short lastSym;    * Most recent symbol encoded 
} LZWCmp

void InsertTrie(LZWCmp *cmp, UChar sym) {
    int init = 0;

    if (cmp->curLoc == NULL) {
    printf("Current Code %u\n", CurCode);
    cmp->curLoc = malloc(sizeof(TrieNode));
    do {
        cmp->curLoc->codes[init] = -1;
        cmp->curLoc->links[init] = NULL;
    } while(++init < NUM_SYMS);

    cmp->curLoc->codes[sym] = CurCode;
 }


int TrieTraverse(LZWCmp *cmp, char *sym) {
    UChar init = 0, result; 
    int size = 1;

    if (cmp->curLoc == NULL) 
        return FALSE;

    do {
        if (init == *sym) {
            cmp->lastSym = cmp->curLoc->codes[init]; // Pack Code
            cmp->curLoc = cmp->curLoc->links[init];
            return TRUE;
        }
    } while(++init < NUM_SYMS && cmp->curLoc != NULL);


}
```

CurCode is a static variable that keeps track of the last code and inserts into the trie Tree first I traverse the Trie Node and then I set curLoc to the specific link which many times is going to be NULL and I malloc creating a new Node but it does work it does not link it just allocates memory Any suggestions advice
Thanks

Comment: Which line is supposed to set the link?

Comment: Sorry, @hyde I just edit my code so basically the root is the dictionary 0 to 255 symbols and for instance code aa goes from the root looks a (index 97) and goes to the link 97 if the link is null

Comment: @hyde we add a new symbol 257 in the index 97 cause last character is a 97 and the rest of the symbols we set to -1 cause they are not going to be used. until

Comment: Please create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained Compilable Example](http://sscce.org/))
— two names and links for the same basic idea.

Comment: Your code seems to have mismatched `{`. This would be apparent if you had proper indentation. Please fix both. There's no sense in asking about invalid code at SO (unless you are specifically asking about the compiler error you get but don't understand or know how to fix).

Comment: In other words, what Jonathan said... see those links, they both have sound advice.